# smart search for textbox and view result in datagridview in search popup screen in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, search, full-text-search

I have a `search popup screen`, Inside the popup screen there are `Textbox`, Go `button` and `DataGridView`.
 On click of Go `button` list of records will be loaded in the `DataGridView`, after this user keyin characters in `Textbox` 
matching records should `load` in `DataGridView` without clicking on go `Button`.

Comment: what so far you done?? post your code

Comment: use textbox keyup event to load data in the data grid for showing data without clicking go button.

Comment: I tried with textchanged event

Comment: what error you facing?? post your code in the question. then only we can able to help you.

Comment: Use a `Boolean` field to indicate whether the `Button` has been clicked. In the `TextChanged` event handler of the `TextBox`, test that flag and, if it's set, call your search method.  In the `Click` event handler of the `Button`, set the flag and call the same search method.

Comment: Having said that, I recommend against searching on the `TextChanged` event directly. If the user wants to enter multiple characters then you'll be searching multiple times for no good reason. Instead, reset (`Stop` and `Start`) a `Timer` on `TextChanged` and then search on the `Tick` of the `Timer`. With a relatively small `Interval`, that will ensure that you don't search needlessly when the user types multiple characters but also don't keep them waiting when they finish typing.